# Generating my own SQL Server SSL Certificate

Tags: sql-server, ssl-certificate

I hear it's possible to make myself a test certificate with MakeCert from Windows SDK, but the beast is 1.5 GB, which I feel reluctant to download for a half-megabyte program.

I do, however, have IIS Resource kit with me, which has selfssl to generate certificate for IIS. Will that work for **SQL Server**?

Is there a more convenient way of generating myself an SSL certificate for **SQL Server** use? I even tried using CREATE CERTIFICATE with TSQL within SQL Server and then have it BACKUP into a file, but with no success.

I must have confused the concept of certificate fundamentally. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

[StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) certificates are free and very useful for testing and certain production environments.

No downloads, no figuring out how to make a self-signed CA cert to issue certificates with.